# javafx collision issue between path(line) with thick stroke and circle

Tags: java, javafx, collision-detection, intersect, stroke

I am using JavaFx 8 library.

My task is simple: I want to check if circle collides with a path that has a thick stroke around it. The problem is that both functions Path.intersect() and Shape.intersect() ignores the stroke around a path/line.

```
Path tempPath = new Path(player.getPath().getElements());
//player.getDot() is Circle
if(tempPath.intersects(player.getDot().getBoundsInParent())){
   Shape intersect = Shape.intersect(tempPath, player.getDot());
   if(intersect.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth() != -1){
      System.out.println("Path Collision occurred"); 
   }
}
```

My path is made out of many LineTo objects.
The format is this:

```
/** Creates path and player dot */
private void createPath() {
    this.path = new Path();
    this.path.setStrokeWidth(20);
    this.path.setStroke(Color.RED);
    this.path.setStrokeLineCap(StrokeLineCap.ROUND);
    this.path.setStrokeLineJoin(StrokeLineJoin.ROUND);

    this.dot = new Circle(10, Color.BLUE);
    this.dot.setOpacity(1);
}
```

How could I implement a successful collision detection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The collision detection works just fine:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.ClosePath;
import javafx.scene.shape.LineTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.MoveTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.Path;
import javafx.scene.shape.Shape;
import javafx.scene.shape.StrokeLineCap;
import javafx.scene.shape.StrokeLineJoin;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

        Circle circle = new Circle(100, 100, 30);
        Path path = new Path();

        double x = 144;

        path.getElements().add(new MoveTo(x, 140));
        path.getElements().add(new LineTo(500, 100));
        path.getElements().add(new ClosePath());

        path.setStrokeWidth(60);
        path.setStrokeLineCap(StrokeLineCap.ROUND);
        path.setStrokeLineJoin(StrokeLineJoin.ROUND);

        Shape shape = Shape.intersect(circle, path);

        boolean intersects = shape.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth() != -1;

        System.out.println("Intersects: " + intersects);

        Pane pane = new Pane();
        pane.getChildren().addAll(circle, path);
        root.setCenter(pane);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Switch x = 144 with x = 145 for testing. The console shows whether there's an intersection or not.

The problem you have is that you're comparing different bounds.

See the documentation of [Node](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html), section "*Bounding Rectangles*" about how the various bounds are calculated.

Comment: you are right, collision works fine. I found out that my bug was in the duplication of Path object. 
    Path tempPath = new Path(player.getPath().getElements());)
The properties of the old path, like Stroke and Color, did not get transferred to the new one. therefore it is needed to reassign properties.